# How does Spring know that ThrowsAdvice.afterThrowing needs to be called?

Tags: spring

How does Spring know that ThrowsAdvice.afterThrowing needs to be called?

I found [documentation on the class here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/aop/ThrowsAdvice.html)  but  I was wondering if anyone has an elegant explanation of how exactly reflection is used to look for that "afterThrowing" method specificially.  I just want to see the code that does that so I can understand it better.

A link to some source code would be a sufficient answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at very old documentation (though the [current one](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/ThrowsAdvice.html) doesn't say much more).

Spring uses a `ThrowsAdviceInterceptor` to handle `ThrowsAdvice`. You can find version `4.1.4.RELEASE` source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-aop/4.1.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/aop/framework/adapter/ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.java#ThrowsAdviceInterceptor).

Its constructor

```
public ThrowsAdviceInterceptor(Object throwsAdvice) {
    Assert.notNull(throwsAdvice, "Advice must not be null");
    this.throwsAdvice = throwsAdvice;

    Method[] methods = throwsAdvice.getClass().getMethods();
    for (Method method : methods) {
        if (method.getName().equals(AFTER_THROWING) &&
                (method.getParameterTypes().length == 1 || method.getParameterTypes().length == 4) &&
                Throwable.class.isAssignableFrom(method.getParameterTypes()[method.getParameterTypes().length - 1])
            ) {
            // Have an exception handler
            this.exceptionHandlerMap.put(method.getParameterTypes()[method.getParameterTypes().length - 1], method);
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Found exception handler method: " + method);
            }
        }
    }

    if (this.exceptionHandlerMap.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "At least one handler method must be found in class [" + throwsAdvice.getClass() + "]");
    }
}
```

scans for appropriate methods and registers them. It then wraps the target method invocation

```
@Override
public Object invoke(MethodInvocation mi) throws Throwable {
    try {
        return mi.proceed();
    }
    catch (Throwable ex) {
        Method handlerMethod = getExceptionHandler(ex);
        if (handlerMethod != null) {
            invokeHandlerMethod(mi, ex, handlerMethod);
        }
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

and invokes the handler if an exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for.   Nice to see the AFTER_THROWING static member.